# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4162, 3]

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, one-hot-encoding

I am facing an error in plotting my confusion matrix. I am giving the test labels and my predicted label in confusion matrix function but it is giving me the value error having the problem in number of samples.

Shape of My data is below.

```
Trainig Data Shape (4162, 224, 224, 3)
Training Data Labels Shape (4162, 5)
Testing Data Shape (3921, 224, 224, 3)
Testing Data Labels Shape (3921, 5)
```

Predicted Label is a bit ugly because of only 2 epochs run, I just wanted to plot the confusion matrix first so thats why.

```
predictingimage = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/78/3/2010/0ba8d018cdc994.jpg" #67/1698/2010/6805eb92ac6c70.jpg"
predictImageRead = mpg.imread(predictingimage)

resizingImage = cv2.cv2.resize(predictImageRead,(224,224))
reshapedFinalImage = np.expand_dims(resizingImage, axis=0)
npimage = np.asarray(reshapedFinalImage)
m = model.predict(npimage)
print(m)
[array([[0.02502811, 0.01959323, 0.6556284 , 0.26472655, 0.03502375]],
      dtype=float32), array([[5.8234303e-04, 3.1917400e-04, 9.4957882e-01, 1.8873921e-02,
        3.0645736e-02]], dtype=float32), array([[0.02581117, 0.04752538, 0.81816435, 0.04812173, 0.06037736]],
      dtype=float32)]

cm = confusion_matrix(train_labels_Encode,m)
plt.imshow(cm)
plt.show()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/ThesisWork/seriouswork/Inception_SVM_CompCarsGoogleNetArchitecture.py", line 299, in <module>
    cm = confusion_matrix(train_labels_hotEncode,n)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 71, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4162, 3]
```

**Classifier Code:**

```
X_train = np.load('D:/Inception_preprocessed_data_Labels_2004/Top5/TrainingData_Top5.npy')#('D:/ThesisWork/S_224_Training_data.npy')#training_images
X_test = np.load('D:/Inception_preprocessed_data_Labels_2004/Top5/TrainingLabels_Top5.npy')#('D:/ThesisWork/S_224_Training_labels.npy')#training_labels
y_train = np.load('D:/Inception_preprocessed_data_Labels_2004/Top5/TestingData_Top5.npy')#('D:/ThesisWork/S_224_Testing_data.npy')#testing_images 
y_test = np.load('D:/Inception_preprocessed_data_Labels_2004/Top5/TestingLabels_Top5.npy')#('D:/ThesisWork/S_224_Testing_labels.npy')#testing_labels
print(X_test)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(X_test)
transform_trainLabels = le.transform(X_test)
print(transform_trainLabels)
print(le.inverse_transform(transform_trainLabels))

train_labels_hotEncode = np_utils.to_categorical(transform_trainLabels,len(set(transform_trainLabels)))
shuffle(X_train)
shuffle(train_labels_hotEncode)
le2 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le2.fit(y_test)
transform_testLabels = le2.transform(y_test)


test_labels_hotEncode = np_utils.to_categorical(transform_testLabels,len(set(transform_testLabels)))
print(test_labels_hotEncode.shape)
shuffle(y_train)
shuffle(test_labels_hotEncode)
# print(train_labels_hotEncode[3000])
# exit()
# X_train = np.asarray(X_train / 255.0)
# y_train = np.asarray(y_train / 255.0)

# print("X_Training" ,X_train.shape, X_train)
# print("X_TEST", X_test.shape)
# print("Y_train", y_train.shape)
# print("y_test", y_test.shape)
# exit()
# plt.imshow(X_train[1])
# print(X_test)
# plt.imshow(y_train[1])
# print(y_test)
# plt.show()

print("Trainig Data Shape",X_train.shape)
print("Training Data Labels Shape",train_labels_hotEncode.shape)
print("Testing Data Shape", y_train.shape)
print("Testing Data Labels Shape", test_labels_hotEncode.shape)

# X_train = np.array(X_train).astype(np.float32)
# y_train = np.array(y_train).astype(np.float32)

def inception_module(image, 
            filters_1x1, 
            filters_3x3_reduce, 
            filter_3x3,
            filters_5x5_reduce,
            filters_5x5, 
            filters_pool_proj, 
            name=None):
  conv_1x1 = Conv2D(filters_1x1, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer= bias_init)(image)
  conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filters_3x3_reduce, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer= bias_init)(image)
  conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filter_3x3,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_3x3)

  conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5_reduce,(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer= bias_init)(image)
  conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_5x5)

  pool_proj = MaxPool2D((3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(image)
  pool_proj = Conv2D(filters_pool_proj, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer= bias_init)(pool_proj)

  output = concatenate([conv_1x1, conv_3x3, conv_5x5, pool_proj], axis=3, name=name)

  return output

kernel_init = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()
bias_init = keras.initializers.Constant(value=0.2)
# IMG_SIZE = 64 
input_layer = Input(shape=(224,224,3))

image = Conv2D(64,(7,7),padding='same', strides=(2,2), activation='relu', name='conv_1_7x7/2', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(input_layer)

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_1_3x3/2')(image)
image = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv_2a_3x3/1' )(image)
image = Conv2D(192, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv_2b_3x3/1')(image)
image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_2_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image,
                    filters_1x1= 64,
                    filters_3x3_reduce= 96,
                    filter_3x3 = 128,
                    filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                    filters_5x5= 32,
                    filters_pool_proj=32,
                    name='inception_3a')

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1=128,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                            filter_3x3=192,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                            filters_5x5=96,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_3b')

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_3_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image, 
                            filters_1x1=192,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                            filter_3x3=208,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                            filters_5x5=48,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_4a')

image1 = AveragePooling2D((5,5), strides=3)(image)
image1 = Conv2D(128, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(image1)
image1 = Flatten()(image1)
image1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(image1)
image1 = Dropout(0.7)(image1)
image1 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_1')(image1)

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1 = 160,
                            filters_3x3_reduce= 112,
                            filter_3x3= 224,
                            filters_5x5_reduce= 24,
                            filters_5x5= 64,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_4b')

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1= 128,
                           filters_3x3_reduce = 128,
                           filter_3x3= 256,
                           filters_5x5_reduce= 24,
                           filters_5x5=64,
                           filters_pool_proj=64,
                           name='inception_4c')

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1=112,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=144,
                           filter_3x3= 288,
                           filters_5x5_reduce= 32,
                           filters_5x5=64,
                           filters_pool_proj=64,
                           name='inception_4d')

image2 = AveragePooling2D((5,5), strides=3)(image)
image2 = Conv2D(128, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(image2)
image2 = Flatten()(image2)
image2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(image2)
image2 = Dropout(0.7)(image2) #Changed from 0.7
image2 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_2')(image2)

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1=256,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                            filter_3x3=320,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                            filters_5x5=128,
                            filters_pool_proj=128,
                            name= 'inception_4e')

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_4_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1=256,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                           filter_3x3= 320,
                           filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                           filters_5x5= 128,
                           filters_pool_proj=128,
                           name='inception_5a')

image = inception_module(image, 
                           filters_1x1=384,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=192,
                           filter_3x3=384,
                           filters_5x5_reduce=48,
                           filters_5x5=128,
                           filters_pool_proj=128,
                           name='inception_5b')

image = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool_5_3x3/1')(image)

image = Dropout(0.7)(image)
image = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='output')(image)

model = Model(input_layer, [image,image1,image2], name='inception_v1')

model.summary()


epochs = 2
initial_lrate = 0.001 # Changed From 0.01

def decay(epoch, steps=100):
  initial_lrate = 0.01
  drop = 0.96
  epochs_drop = 8
  lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop,math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))#
  return lrate

sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# nadam = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr= 0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None)
# keras
lr_sc = LearningRateScheduler(decay)
# rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr = initial_lrate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
# ad = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=initial_lrate)
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'],loss_weights=[1,0.3,0.3], optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'

history = model.fit(X_train, [train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode], validation_split=0.3,shuffle=True,epochs=epochs, batch_size= 32, callbacks=[lr_sc]) # batch size changed from 256 or 64 to 16(y_train,[y_test,y_test,y_test])
# validation_data=(y_train,[test_labels_hotEncode,test_labels_hotEncode,test_labels_hotEncode]), validation_data= (X_train, [train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode]),

print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['output_acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_output_acc'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'],loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()






# predictingimage = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/78/3/2010/0ba8d018cdc994.jpg" #67/1698/2010/6805eb92ac6c70.jpg"
predictImageRead =  X_train
# resizingImage = cv2.cv2.resize(predictImageRead,(224,224))
# reshapedFinalImage = np.expand_dims(predictImageRead, axis=0)

# print(reshapedFinalImage.shape)
# npimage = np.array(reshapedFinalImage)
m = model.predict(predictImageRead)
print(m)
print(predictImageRead.shape)
print(train_labels_hotEncode)
# print(m.shape)
plt.imshow(predictImageRead[1])
plt.show()
# n = np.argmax(m,axis=-1)
# n = np.array(m)
print(confusion_matrix(X_test,m[0]))
cm = confusion_matrix(X_test,m[0])
plt.imshow(cm)
plt.show()
```

Please guide me through this.

Thanks!

Comment: could you add the complete error ?

Comment: @CoMartel I edited the question with the error.#

Comment: could you had the shapes of reshapedFinalImage , train_label_Encode and m ?

Comment: Reshaped Final Image Shape: ((1, 224, 224, 3))
TrainLabelsEncodeShape: (4162, 224, 224, 3)
and there is no shape of m as it is a list.

Comment: @CoMartel Can you check it now?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You want to compute the confusion matrix. You need as many predictions for that as many labels you have. Why are you only predicting one image?

Comment: @markuscosinus this was confusing me. As I am validating my data with 30% of my training data. How can do it and plot a confusion matrix.

Comment: Could you add the construction of your model?

Comment: you mean my code for my classifier? I am using Inception googleNet

Comment: I added my Classifier code also @markuscosinus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute a confusion matrix of your training data you have to make your moddel predict **all** your training examples, roughly like this:

```
m = model.predict(train_data) # train_data should have the shape (4162, 224, 224, 3)
```

`m` should then have a length of `4162` and you can plot the confusion matrix like this:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(train_labels_Encode, m)
plt.imshow(cm)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you. But I still am encountering the same error, My prediction is something like this, as I am just running it on 2 epochs to get the result faster and then try to run confusion matrix on it. `[array([[0.00222767, 0.00141662, 0.24431719, 0.7308634 , 0.02117508],
       [0.00222767, 0.00141662, 0.24431717, 0.7308635 , 0.02117508],
       [0.00222767, 0.00141662, 0.24431719, 0.7308634 , 0.02117508],
       ...,`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ", print(confusion_matrix(train_labels_hotEncode,m))
      y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 71, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4162, 3]`

Comment: Its same that I gave in my question. Nothing changed

Comment: Thats weird. can you try this and post the error message?
`cm = confusion_matrix(train_labels_Encode, m[0])`

Comment: I just did.. And now its giving me value error
`ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets`